# Not able to mount dockerized NFS server : requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, nfs, nfsclient

My docker engine is running on Ubuntu 16.

I tried to setup NFS server based on : Using https://github.com/ErezHorev/dockerized_nfs_server/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile

NFS server is running now .  container IP is 172.17.0.2

But I am not able to mount in same container or from other container .

Error :

```
root@71d5a4bc32bc:/#  mount -v -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 172.17.0.2:/exports/opt /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Aug  9 13:06:36 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=2049,vers=4,addr=172.17.0.2,clientaddr=172.17.0.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=2049,addr=172.17.0.2'
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered

**mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported**
```

Debugging

```
root@71d5a4bc32bc:/# rpcinfo
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100024    1    udp       0.0.0.0.146.187        status     102
    100024    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.225.53         status     102
    100024    1    udp6      ::.221.215             status     102
    100024    1    tcp6      ::.237.126             status     102


root@71d5a4bc32bc:/# rpcinfo -p 172.17.0.2
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  37563  status
    100024    1   tcp  57653  status
```

**root@71d5a4bc32bc:/#  showmount -e 172.17.0.2
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered**

**Edit**

When I ran

service nfs-kernel-server start

```
mount: permission denied
 * Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                                                                                                                                                  


exportfs: could not open /proc/fs/nfs/exports for locking: errno 13 (Permission denied)
                                                                                                                                                                                                            [ OK ]
 * Starting NFS kernel daemon                                                                                                                                                                                      rpc.nfsd: Unable to access /proc/fs/nfsd errno 2 (No such file or directory).


Please try, as root, 'mount -t nfsd nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd' and then restart rpc.nfsd to correct the problem
```

Port 2049 was never up .

Comment: `docker` containers are still using your host's kernel, so they only have access to the facilities your host has compiled and loaded. Thus, you can't avoid needing to load (if modularized), or recompile with (if not) kernel modules that are effective prerequisites for functionality.

Comment: did you run the container using `--priveleged` flag in your `docker run` command?